# How to plot the real line in SageMath

Tags: math, graph, sage

I am preparing a SageMath Jupyter notebook for expository purposes. I would like to be able to display the real line, with chosen points on it, and some arrows between certain pairs of points.

While this would be easy to do in LaTeX (by means of TikZ), I do not know how to do it in Sage. This feels like something that should be well within Sage's capabilities. What to do?

To be precise - say I want to produce essentially the same output as the following TikZ code.

```
\def\scale{2}
\def\bet{0.2}
\draw[-] (-\scale*3.5,0) -- (\scale*3.5,0); 
\foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
  \draw[shift={(\scale*\i,0)},color=gray] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\frac{\i}{q}$};
  \filldraw (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet,0) circle (2pt) node[above] {$\frac{\i}{q}+\beta$};
}
\foreach \i in {-3,...,-2} {
  \draw[*->*] (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet-0.08,0.04) to[bend right] (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet+\scale+0.08,0.04);
}
\draw[*->] (-\scale+\scale*\bet-0.08,0.04) to[bend right] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't think there are (currently) nice ways to do this. But it would be pretty straightforward to write something that would make (labelled) dots on the line, and sage has nice straight arrow and Bezier arrow graphics. It's not ready-made, but it wouldn't be too hard I make work.

Comment: Can one, for instance, do what the following TikZ code does? How?

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\scale{2}
    \def\bet{0.2}
    \draw[-] (-\scale*3.5,0) -- (\scale*3.5,0); 
    \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
      \draw[shift={(\scale*\i,0)},color=gray] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\frac{\i}{q}$};
      \filldraw (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet,0) circle (2pt) node[above] {$\frac{\i}{q}+\beta$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {-3,...,-2} {
      \draw[*->*] (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet-0.08,0.04) to[bend right] 
    (\scale*\i+\scale*\bet+\scale+0.08,0.04);
    }
    \draw[*->] (-\scale+\scale*\bet-0.08,0.04) to[bend right] (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: That didn't format well - let me include it in the question.